# how to pass selectmany combine with groupby to MVC view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller, c#-4.0, lambda

i have the following lambda expression in MVC application.

```
 var toprating=  _db.Movie.SelectMany(m => m.Rating.Select(r=> new 

            {

           movieID=r.MovieID,
           MovieTitle= m.Title
            })).GroupBy(m=>m.movieID).ToList();

      ViewBag.TopMovie = toprating;
        }
```

i want to pass this to my view.
i try writing the following in my view

```
 IEnumerable<Movie> TopMovies = ViewBag.TopMovie;
```

but got this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Movie>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

any help will be appriciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i would recommend that you make a class that depicts your domain entity (Movie) like

```
public class MyMovie{
 public int movieID { get; set; }
 public string MovieTitle { get; set; }  
}
```

and modify your *linq* query as

```
var toprating=  _db.Movie.SelectMany(m => m.Rating.Select(r=> new MyMovie
            {
              movieID=r.MovieID,
              MovieTitle= m.Title
            })).GroupBy(m=>m.movieID).ToList();

ViewBag.TopMovie = toprating;
IEnumerable<MyMovie> TopMovies = ViewBag.TopMovie;
```

i have assumed that the Movie is your Domain entity, use view models to pass on to the views.

you may find [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901854/linq-how-to-declare-ienumerableanonymoustype) helpful