# how to Use select many in lambda expression mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-4, lambda

i have the following lambda expression in MVC application.i want to group data.

```
 var toprating=  _db.Movie.SelectMany(m => m.Rating.Select(r=> new 

            {

           movieID=r.MovieID,
           MovieTitle= m.Title
            })).GroupBy(m=>m.movieID).ToList();

      ViewBag.TopMovie = toprating;
        }
```

i want to pass this to my view.
i try writing the following in my view

```
 IEnumerable<Movie> TopMovies = ViewBag.TopMovie;
```

but got this error

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Movie>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Is the type on ViewBag.TopMovie object? you probably either need to change its type or cast it to IEnumerable<Movie>.

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to pass selectmany combine with groupby to MVC view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9751825/how-to-pass-selectmany-combine-with-groupby-to-mvc-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of the collection that you are passing in **isn’t** an `IEnumerable<Movie>`. Notice you are using an anonymous type, and then you’re also using `GroupBy`. The resulting type is complex.

Your query is also meaningless because you’re accessing `Rating` but not using it, so you probably end up with multiple copies of the same movie, and with all the rating information discarded. For the moment I’ll assume you actually *want* the ratings included.

So you could use the following query, for example:

```
ViewBag.Ratings = _db.Movie.SelectMany(m => m.Rating.Select(r => new 
{
    Movie = m,
    Rating = r
})).GroupBy(m => m.Movie, m => m.Rating).ToList();
```

Now the type of the above query is `List<IGrouping<Movie, Rating>>`, so you can use that in your view:

```
List<IGrouping<Movie, Rating>> ratings = ViewBag.Ratings;
```

Comment: that was the right answer but i want the movie to occur only once and print in sequence highest number rating. if highest rated movie is 5 time let it be number one follow by the one rated 4 time and so on .thanks

Comment: @JED: Right, so you want to use `.Count` to determine number of ratings and `.OrderByDescending` to sort by it. :)

Comment: thanks i have finally solve the problem with the following code    var toprating = _db.Movie.
               SelectMany(m => m.Rating.GroupBy(t=>t.Movie).Select(r => new AssingTopMovieRating
             {
                 MovieId = m.MovieID,
                 MovieTitle = m.Title,
                 CountMovieId=r.Count()
             })).OrderByDescending(r=>r.CountMovieId);

Comment: @JED: Well done :) Although I would personally recommend to call it “Rating” or “RatingCount” instead of “CountMovieId”, and perhaps you should also rethink the name of that class — I mean, “assing”? What?

Comment: @JED: I still don’t know why it has the word “assign” in it. Type names should be nouns or noun phrases. If the type encapsulates a movie rating, perhaps it should be called just `MovieRating`?

Answer (score 3):

The ViewBag is a dynamic object (a feature introduced with .NET 4.0) and thus .NET does not know what type any of the properties on the object is. Since .NET is not aware of the type, you must explicitly cast any properties on the ViewBag if you want to store them in a variable.

```
 var topMovies = ViewBag.TopMovie as IEnumerable<Movie>;
```

And to convert anything to the type of Movie you will need to change your original LINQ query to select Movies and not anonymous types.

Comment: i think the is because of select new. the movieID=
MovieTitle= have no difinition type

Comment: What are you really trying to select in your original query? It seemes strange to select all ratings for all movies. Do you need the average rating for each movie?

Answer (score 0):

It is because of the anonymous object in your SelectMany as well as the GroupBy.

GroupBy does not return an IEnumerable, but rather [`IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501.aspx) - essentially a collection of collections where each sub collection has the same key value.

In the case you have, grouping by the movie Id is going to give you a rather strange collection:

```
toprating: [
    [
       // MovieID, Movie Title
        { 1, Movie1Title },   // one Id/title pair for every rating.
        { 1, Movie1Title },
        { 1, Movie1Title },
        ...
    ],
    [
        { 2, Movie2Title },   // one title for every rating.
        { 2, Movie2Title },
        { 2, Movie2Title },
        ...
    ]
]
```

Something like that, but if that's really what you want, okay.  Then in your view, you're trying to do this:

```
IEnumerable<Movie> TopMovies = ViewBag.TopMovie;
```

But TopMovie is `IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, object>>`.  So of course it can't be cast to a Movie.

This will give you the object and allow you enumerate over it:

```
IEnumerable<IGrouping<int, object>> TopMovies = ViewBag.TopMovie;
```

I suspect though that this isn't what you're actually wanting to do, but I can't help without more information.